# Mac OSX VirtualBox and Windows 7 Guest from External HD

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have a 2014 MacBook Air, and wanted to run a win 7 installation that I have in VirtualBox every now and then.

I used VM's VCenter Converter to make a   .VMDK image of my current Win 7 installation. I have now moved this to an external HD due to the file size and the MacBook Air having limited space.

I created a virtual machine in VirtualBox, and selected the option of use existing HD and selected the .VMDK file from the external HD (/Volumes/My Book/VM_Img/James-PC/James-PC.vmdk)

VirtualBox has no problems accessing this. Then I start the virtual machine and I get a BSOD followed by a automatic reboot of the Virtual Machine (I am not quick enough to see the BSOD error.) then the windows startup repair runs and then fails with an error of:

Repair action : system files integrity check and repair

Result : failed error code 0x490

I'm not sure why this is happening. I'm assuming that it is working in some way as I am able to boot the windows systems repair tool just not the windows installation

Any advice would be most gratefully received

James

Comment: I want to clarify, you used 'VM's VCenter Converter' from VM-Ware and use the output to virtualbox?

Comment: Yes, I ised VCenter converter to generate the .vmdk file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so people are aware, I have sorted the issue now.

I had the use Disk2VHD to create a virtual copy of the HD. I had to make sure it was in the .VHD format, I also needed to mount the .vhd to VirtualBox to the IDE controller not the SATA controller (which is the default

Windows boots from the image of the disc which is stored on an external HD without issue and then starts installing necessary drivers.

Thanks for all the help

James